Regex does or does not give an error depending on which REPL is used
Consider the following Python code using the regex library re
import re
re.compile(rf"{''.join(['{c}\\s*' for c in 'qqqq'])}")

I have run it in two different REPLs:
https://www.pythonmorsels.com/repl/
https://www.online-python.com/#google_vignette
The first of which gives no error, and the second give the following error:
File "main.py", line 2
    re.compile(rf"{''.join(['{c}\\s*' for c in 'qqqq'])}")
               ^
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

I'd like to understand why I get an error sometimes and not others. How can I proceed to narrow down exactly where the difference is?

Now try Python itself? And then give what you wrote a quick think: rf makes no sense because r means "raw string", i.e. everything inside the delimiters is literally what it is, there is no hidden meaning or replacements or escapes etc., whereas f means "formatted string" where {...} does the exact opposite of what r claims is going to happen. But then to make it even more curious: your join already forms an appropriately defined string, why would you then wrap that in an otherwise empty string? Just say re.compile(''.join(['{c}\\s*' for c in 'qqqq'])), done.

"Is this due to a different version of python?" you ask, without bothering to report the versions of Python on your friend's machine and yours.

@Kaz, Thanks for pointing out the confusion. I have simplified the question to focus only on the repls. Please proceed with this change in mind

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I agree, this is a strange thing to do, I dont plan to use this code, I am simply interested in the fact that there is a difference in behaviour on one repl vs another

I'm not saying it's a "strange thing to do", I am pointing out it's an "impossible thing to do": something can't be a "raw and not raw" string at the same time. Understanding why two services deal with complete nonsense in different ways does not teach us anything. What you should be doing here, if you genuinely care, is to see what Python says, and then contact the maintainers of the service that doesn't generate the correct result, so they can fix their website.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans “Raw formatted” strings make perfect sense, the “raw” part means don’t interpret backslash escapes in the string part, “formatted” means there are interpolated expressions. I used a “rf” string to build a regular expression once (please don’t crucify me for the regular expression part, I was young and inexperienced)

The second one which gives the syntax error, is running Python 3.8.5, which was before PEP 701 was added to Python. PEP 701 finally added f-strings to the Python 3.12 parser so they can contain any valid expression which includes strings with a backslash. Pre-3.12 python postprocesses f-strings with a weird ad hoc parser that gets really confused when it sees a backlash inside an expression part.
The first online REPL that gives no error is running Python 3.12.0.

You can get around the problem with:
import re
re.compile("{0}".format(''.join([fr'{c}\s*' for c in 'qqqq'])))

This works on both repls you provided. It sends 'q\s*q\s*q\s*q\s*' to re.compile.
I'm assuming that the '\\s' was meant to reduce to '\s'.
